# Data size after gated convolution for language modeling

Tags: nlp, convolution

I recently read following paper about language modeling with CNN.

*Language Modeling with Gated Convolutional Networks
https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.08083*

In this paper, they use below picture as their model. But I am not sure about `Convolution` figure (third layer). Usually to apply CNNs for text embeddings, filter size is `(filter_h, embedding_size)`. So the data size after the convolution is `(seq_len-filter_h+1, 1)` with `stride==1`. See a bottom figure.

But in this figure, the height of the data size after the Convolution is still large (I mean larger than 1). So if I try to implement this, it needs many padding to expand columns.
Actually I found [an reproduced code](https://github.com/anantzoid/Language-Modeling-GatedCNN/blob/master/model.py#L62) at github. Yes, it looks they also use so many padding for the columns with `padding=SAME`.

Why they are using so many paddings? Many paddings doesn't make sense for me..

[image]

[image]